# What is wrong in this LINQ Query, getting compile error

Tags: string, linq, list

I have a list `AllIDs`:

```
List<IAddress> AllIDs = new List<IAddress>();
```

I want to do `substring` operation on a member field `AddressId` based on a character "_".

I am using below LINQ query but getting compilation error:

```
AllIDs= AllIDs.Where(s => s.AddressId.Length >= s.AddressId.IndexOf("_"))
    .Select(s => s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")))
    .ToList();
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyCompany.Common.Users.IAddress>'

Answer (score 3):

`AllIDs` is a list of `IAddress` but you are selecting a `string`. The compiler is complaining it cannot convert a `List<string>` to a `List<IAddress>`. Did you mean the following instead?

```
var substrings = AllIDs.Where(...).Select(...).ToList();
```

Comment: But Problem is I want to provide the resultant list as a datasource for a dropdown. And the resultant List does not have the property AddressID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put them back into `Address` objects (assuming you have an `Address` class in addition to your `IAddress` interface), you can do something like this (assuming the constructor for `Address` is in place):

```
AllIDs = AllIDs.Where(...).Select(new Address(s.AddressID.Substring(s.AddressID.IndexOf("_")))).ToList();
```

You should also look at using query syntax for LINQ instead of method syntax, it can clean up and improve the readability of a lot of queries like this.  Your original (unmodified) query is roughly equivalent to this:

```
var substrings = from a in AllIDs
                 let id = a.AddressId
                 let idx = id.IndexOf("_")
                 where id.Length >= idx
                 select id.Substring(idx);
```

Though this is really just a style thing, and this compiles to the same thing as the original.  One slight difference is that you only have to call `String.IndexOf()` one per entry, instead of twice per entry.  `let` is your friend.

Comment: Hi Matthew thanks for the response.

But Problem is I want to provide the resultant list in your example substrings as a datasource for a dropdown. And the resultant List will not have the property AddressID which is being used as below.


ddl.DataSource = AllIDs;
ddl.DataTextField = "AddressID";
ddl.DataValueField = "AddressID";
ddl.DataBind();

I can use ForEach but want to do it using LINQ. Any pointers??

Comment: Look at wasp's solution, it should work with this databinding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
var boundable  = 
    from s id in AllIDs
    where s.AddressId.Length >= s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")
    select new { AddressId = s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")) };
boundable = boundable.ToList();
```